# SVC not resolving on MNIST

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, svm, mnist

I'm using the following code to break up MNIST and run an SVM:

```
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1)
X, y = mnist['data'], mnist['target']
y = y.astype(np.uint8)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[:60000], X[60000:], y[:60000], y[60000:]
svm_clf = SVC()
svm_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Last night I left that to run. Three hours later and it still hadn't resolved.

I get the future warning

```
FutureWarning: The default value of gamma will change from 'auto' to 'scale' in version 0.22 to account better for unscaled features. Set gamma explicitly to 'auto' or 'scale' to avoid this warning.
  "avoid this warning.", FutureWarning)
```

but I can't imagine that not setting the gamma would affect it this way.

I'm running Python 3.6.7 in Jupyter 5.7.8.

Comment: SVMs are slow to train and you also have too many samples to train on, first try reducing the training size to around 5000-10000 then test the accuracy and then you can train on another batch of 5k samples. The warning has nothing to do with training time.

Comment: It's probably not about gamma. One thing that definitely makes it so slow is that SVM is by definition a binary classifier. When you use it with multiple classes, Scikit-Learn trains a model for every pair of classes (2^10, I believe). So it's long because you're training dozens of classifiers. Additionally, you're not using LinearSVC, so the non-linearity is a thousand times slower.

Comment: If you are using `sklearn` to train the model, running using Colab on GPU will not help because `sklearn` models by default are meant to run on CPUs only. Training time of binary classifier depends on the type of algorithm you are using, there is always a trade-off between speed and accuracy. You can try out Decision Trees, Neural Networks etc. they might train in less time.

Comment: as @techytushar said, try to reduce the samples at 100 first to see if it is working or it gets stuck and then if everything looks okay increase it further.

Comment: Whelp. A training set of 200 takes a second, a training set of 2000 takes 5 seconds, and the training set of 20,000 is still going strong. Like Geron says, SVM scales terribly; I guess this is me learning it in action. Thanks everybody for all your help.

Comment: What is your `sklearn` version ?

Comment: @makis I'm running 0.20.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, there is no solution. As the number of training vectors increase so does the training time.

Reference: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#complexity

[image]

Just for the record, SVMs are great for these problems (see here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_digits_classification.html) but when the dataset is huge they become slow.

---

EDIT 1: In sklearn [website](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) there is this:

> The implementation is based on libsvm. The fit time scales at least
>   quadratically with the number of samples and may be impractical beyond
>   tens of thousands of samples. For large datasets consider using
>   sklearn.linear_model.LinearSVC or sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier
>   instead, possibly after a sklearn.kernel_approximation.Nystroem
>   transformer.

Comment: Is that to suggest that using SVM as a multiclass is generally ill-advised?

Comment: No. SVMs are great tools for multiclass problems. The problem is when you have a huge dataset. Then they become very slow.

Comment: Is there a particular balance that the industry seeks out in terms of training time/accuracy for the size of a dataset? In other words, is there a best practice for data science in general, a barrier at which point an SVM is recommended against?

Comment: In my opinion no. But it's your call what model you will use. A better way to approach your problem would be to use K-Folds that will naturally split the data into smaller batches.

Comment: In other words, something along the lines of `cross_val_predict(SVC(), X_train, y_train, cv=5)`?

Comment: Yes. And maybe you even use more than 5. Something like 15 if you use the whole mnist dataset.

Comment: On the tails of that, does OvR affect the speed of the training as well, as opposed to OvO?

Comment: Of course. OVR would be slower. See the edit in my answer